# Getting mixed active content error after adding SSL to my website

Tags: reactjs, express, ssl

I have a https frontend which is making requests to the backend. After adding ssl certificate my requests are getting blocked. I cannot make my backend api https. What should i do?
FYI:
The frontend server is react, the backend is express and i am running nginx.

Comment: "Mixed content" means that the HTML page loaded via https wants to load additional resources via http, which is blocked for security reasons.

Comment: It is fetching articles from the backend which is http.

Comment: If you want security (SSL) for your website, you must not introduce security gaps by loading parts of it without SSL. Your backend must then also support SSL.

Comment: Can i provide SSL without buying domain for it?

Comment: Don't know. Can you let your frontend server (which supports SSL) act as a proxy to your backend? The proxy could access the backend via http, this would not compromise the security of the website (at least the browser won't complain). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72577752/16462950

Comment: If i understood you correctly I think it is doing exactly that. My frontend is just making requests to the backend. The backend is just an api

Comment: Who makes the requests? The browser or the frontend _server_ (that is, the server that also serves the HTML page via SSL)? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71717333/16462950

Comment: When the frontend server is loading content from the db it makes a get request to the backend server which serves as an api in this case.

Comment: That sounds as if your backend must also support SSL. Sorry.

Comment: It is on localhost. I cannot make it support ssl

Comment: Where is your frontend server, then?

Comment: I mean i am making request to http://IPADRESS:PORT/api. I must have a separate domain for it to make it support ssl, right?

Comment: The SSL-capable server that serves my HTML page makes the request to the backend server which runs on different port. And the website is online. Only the frontend server and it needs to be ssl certified.

Comment: Where are your backend requests getting blocked, then? Please add more detail about the error to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make https requests to the backend server, i just set it as a subdomain and it all worked.